# Why is my textField function is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I added a function to my code using Swift that allows the user to hit return on the keyboard to dismiss it, but it's not working and I am not sure why. Can someone lead me in the right direction please?

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var item: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

        toDoList.append(item.text)
        item.text = ""

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(toDoList, forKey: "toDoList")


    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        item.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this change:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

And make sure the delegate of the UITextField is set to an instance of SecondViewController.

Answer (score 0):

set the delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
item.delegate = self
```

Then dismiss the textField like so:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    if textField == item {
        item.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```